# Access to the path "StimulsoftReportsResources" is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, report, reporting, stimulsoft

I getting error `Access to the path "StimulsoftReportsResources" is denied`.
I do not know where the problem comes from. For about a year now, the application has been working without any problems, but suddenly this error occurs when printing and the number of requests for a report increases.
**Fixed a temporary issue**
by recycle `iis` Fixed a temporary issue but printing is very slow

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. my Problem soled by set access for path (properties/security/ ...). this action is not safe and I don't recommend . I think best way for use stimulsoftreport is save reports in database (save binary).

Comment: save binary not means.I have the same report with different information

Comment: @alireza i means save the mrt in the database. that is like use mrt file. if you save mrt file in database you have not to set access for path .

Comment: thanks a lot. This problem occurs when the number of requests for a report increases and you do not normally exist